# ES6: Bad character escape sequence creating ASCII string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ascii, template-literals

Here's my code:

```
let padded = "03";
ascii = `\u00${padded}`;
```

However, I receive `Bad character escape sequence` from Babel. I'm trying to end up with:

`\u0003`

in the `ascii` variable. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ended up with `ascii = (eval('"\\u00' + padded + '"'));`

Comment: Uh? The `eval` solution yields the same result as`String.fromCodePoint`...

Comment: Don't provide your own answer in the question. If you think you have the answer, then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

A unicode escape sequence is basically atomic. You cannot really build one dynamically. Template literals basically perform string concatenation, so your code is equivalent to

```
'\00' + padded
```

It should be obvious now why you get that error. If you want to get the corresponding unicode character you can instead use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) or [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
String.fromCodePoint(3)
```

---

If you want a string that *literally* contains the character sequence `\u0003`, then you just need to escape the escape character to produce a literal backslash:

```
`\\u00${padded}`
```

Comment: Oh I see! "You cannot really build one dynamically" is this not really a thing then? Is there no way of doing it?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `String.fromCodePoint`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint or alternatively (ES5): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode .

Comment: Not sure entirely what I'm doing wrong, but running `String.fromCodePoint(0x404);` doesn't yield `// "\u0404"`, but `"Є"`. Any idea?

Comment: Wait, you literally want a string `"\u0003"`? Why not `ascii = \`\\u00${padded}\`;` then? Because as Felix points out, `String.fromCodePoint(0x404) === "\u0404"`

Comment: @benhowdle89: `"\u0404"` **is** `"Є"`. `\uxxxx` is an escape sequence. It gets replaced by the character it represents.

Comment: @RGraham Yep, I need the string `\u0003`. Your solution outputs `\\u0003` (note the extra backslash)

Comment: @FelixKling Ah sorry, maybe I didn't explain very well. I need that exact string, ie. `\u0003`

Comment: @benhowdle89 I think you may be confusing the escape sequence `\\\` for two characters. It's not, it's just one. Here's [an example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20padded%20%3D%20%2203%22%3B%0Aconst%20ascii%20%3D%20%60%5C%5C00%24%7Bpadded%7D%60%3B%0Aconsole.log(ascii)%3B)

Comment: @benhowdle89: It seems you are confusing something here. If you want the string **value** to literally consist of a ``\`` followed by a `u`, followed by a `0`, etc, then you need to escape the ``\`` just like RGraham said. If you want a string that contains the character that is represented by the escape sequence `"\u0003"`, then you can use `fromCodePoint`. Lets simplify: Take the escape sequence `"\n"`, which represents a line break. Do you want a string that contains a line break or do you want a string that contains ``\`` followed by `n`?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, the latter.

Comment: @benhowdle89: Since the order of solutions is different in my two questions, I still don't know what you want... however, I updated my answer.  Choose whatever you need.