# Using ES6 templates for dynamic character generation

Tags: javascript, restriction, template-literals

While I understand that one can readily use:

```
x="\141"; alert(`${x}`)
```

and get the string `a` in the resulting alert dialog, what if you were dynamically generating the value of `x` based off a dynamic value?

Let's say instead of Octal 141, I was to pass Octal 101 instead? Or Octal whatever...? Is there a way to build the escape code octal character string without using `eval` that may (or may not) use the ES6 template... But not without resorting to using `String.fromCharCode()`?

As to my reasons behind the restrictions, I'm testing the limits of reduced reliance of functions for a personal project.

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873982/es6-bad-character-escape-sequence-creating-ascii-string

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do what you want to do without using a parser method or evaluating the concatenated string. Literals are evaluated once at execute time. Also, you can't concatenate an escape symbol with anything and expect this to behave in a special way, it will always produce a string.